# XBMC starting after login insted of gnome

Tags: gnome, 13.04, autostart, xbmc

I Have a problem. In my Ubuntu 13.04 i have 3 users, one of them suddenly get xbmc starter right after login. How I can change this and restore oryginal settings(gnome,Unity) desktop for this user. Admin account is working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the login **click on the icon next to the name** and select the required session such as **GNOME**, **UNITY** or **XBMC**.

The **selected session** will then become your **default session** for future logins.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, i do not have icon like this. I remember it was there, but disappeared.